# extracting lines of text from a long file

Tags: linux, shell, text-processing, scripting

I have the following text file:

```
#unimportant comment
#possible more unimportant comments
#info1 info2 info3 ,importantname1
importanttext1
#info1 info2 info3 ,importantname2
importanttext2
#info1 info2 info3 ,importantname3
importanttext3
```

I want to break each file down into separate files. All I really need is to extract the non-commented urls , preserving comments is optional. I want each file to be named such as importantname1.txt or the name following the comma at the end of each comment line appended with .txt

so importantname1.txt would have the following contents:

```
importanttext1
```

or possibly

```
#info1 info2 info3 ,importantname1
importanttext1
```

so the line would be extracted and saved with the filename after the comment and appended with .txt in this case filename importantname1.txt

In need to do this for each set of lines in the example file. Preserving the comments is unimportant but I need it to be script-able. I also need to account for an unknown number of comment lines in the header. The comment line will always be there before each importanttextX line

Comment: Will `importanttext` always be a single line, or are multiple lines possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
awk -F, '/^#/{f=$NF".txt";cmt=$0; next} {printf "%s\n%s\n",cmt,$0 >f; close(f)}' file
```

#### Example

Applied to your sample input:

```
$ awk -F, '/^#/{f=$NF".txt";cmt=$0; next} {printf "%s\n%s\n",cmt,$0 >f; close(f)}' file
```

After the above is run, the following files are in the directory:

```
$ ls
file  importantname1.txt  importantname2.txt  importantname3.txt
```

The contents of the new files are:

```
$ cat importantname1.txt 
#info1 info2 info3 ,importantname1
importanttext1
$ cat importantname2.txt 
#info1 info2 info3 ,importantname2
importanttext2
$ cat importantname3.txt 
#info1 info2 info3 ,importantname3
importanttext3
```

#### How it works

Awk reads through the input file line by line.  Our script classifies those lines as comments or not-comments.  For comment lines, the file name and comment is saved.  For non-comments, a new file is created and printed

- `-F,

  This tells awk to use a comma as the field separator on input.  In this way, the file name will always be the last field.
- `/^#/{f=$NF".txt";cmt=$0; next}`

  If a line begins with `#`, we save the last field, `$NF`, plus `.txt` as a file name `f`.  The whole of the comment line is saved as `cmt`.  We then tell awk to skip the rest of the commands and jump to start over on the `next` line.
- `printf "%s\n%s\n",cmt,$0 >f; close(f)`

  For non-comment lines, we print the last seen comment, `cmt`, and the current line, `$0`, into last seen file name `f`.  We then close the file handle for `f`.

#### Protecting against bad file names

If the fields that are to be used as file names contain `/`, the OS will interpret the file names as including directories.  To avoid that, we can replace all `/` with `-` using `gsub(/\//, "-", f)` as follows:

```
awk -F, '/^#/{f=$NF".txt";gsub(/\//, "-", f); cmt=$0; next} {printf "%s\n%s\n",cmt,$0 >f; close(f)}' file
```

Comment: Seems to work but I think I am running into an issue with a "/" character which may need to be escaped or otherwise manipulated for a filename. Maybe replacing "/" with "-"  ?

Comment: @user178167 Yes, slashes would cause problems and your suggestion is excellent.  See update to the answer for code to make the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `grep` and `csplit` could do the job, by a) `grep`ping all non-commeneted lines plus the preceeding info one and b) splitting the output based on the info comment line:

```
grep -v -B1 '^#' file | csplit -z - '/^#/' '{*}'
```

I.e. do not `-v` extract lines that have a # at the beginning `^#` but one line preceeding such lines `-B1`. Then split the incoming piped input `-` at each # at the beginning of a line, ignore empty files `-z` and do so as often as possible `{*}`.

Renaming would have to be a separate step (`csplit` autonames the outpit as xx00, xx01 ... - change pre- and suffix with the `-f` and `-b` options, repectively)

```
#/bin/bash
for f in xx* ; do
   mv "$f" "$( sed -n '2p' "$f" )".txt
done
```